# problemas al insertar datos de Excel a DB - nginx

Tags: php, nginx

Estoy intentando subir los datos de un documento de excel a una base de datos. Me funciona con menos de 1200 filas, pero con más me genera error 502 (Bad Gateway). El excel que intento subir contiene 30.000 filas.

En el log del servidor sale este error:

> 2016/06/06 20:43:13 [error] 6569#0: *113 recv() failed (104:
>   Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 127.0.0.1, server: creditos.app, request: "POST /subidaExcel
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "creditos.app", referrer: "http://creditos.app/subidaExcel"

Hay alguna configuración que deba hacer en NGINX o PHP para que funcione?

Este es el archivo [www.conf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx95H-Bpf7LANjcxQzZiQ1p0Ujg)

Comment: Revisa los logs del servidor y mira el error exacto que te genera, luego colocalos en tu pregunta.

Comment: @JuanPinzón ya edité la pregunta. :)

Comment: Si usas PHP-fpm, puedes colocar el contenido del archivo www.conf??, el error puede ser debido a algun parametro de configuracion.

Comment: @JuanPinzón, ya subi el archivo. Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: @JuanPinzón lo logré solucionar. el problema estaba en el www.conf. Me ayudó muchisimo. Ya publico la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la respuesta. (LINUX)

En el archivo `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` hay una linea de código que dice

> request_terminate_timeout = 128

lo único que hice fué cambiarlo a

> request_terminate_timeout = 3000

Finalmente hay que reiniciar los servicios FPM y NGINX.

> sudo service php5-fpm restart
>
> sudo service nginx restart